# MS access Data type mismatch in criteria expression c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select

I have error, i want to do a filter, which consist some combobox and datetimepicker and it's will be show in dategridview. And when i want select date from datebase, i have this error:

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

```
string strSql1 = @"Select * from GGG where 
                   device_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' 
                   AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' 
                   AND time_id Between 'date1' AND 'date2'";`

string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Ирина\\Desktop\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\BD3.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

string date1 = metroDateTime1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace('.', '/');
string date2 = metroDateTime3.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace('.', '/');

//string strSql = ("SELECT * FROM GGG where device_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' ");
string strSql1 = "Select * from table1 where device_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' AND time_id Between 'date1' AND 'date2'";

//string strSql = "SELECT event_id, device_id, parameter_id, parameter_int_id, time_id, user_id FROM table1 where time_id between #" + metroDateTime1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND #" + metroDateTime3.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "" "# AND #" device_id LIKE '%" + comboBox2.Text + "%' "# AND #" parameter_id LIKE '%" + comboBox3.Text + "%' ");
//string strSql = "SELECT event_id, device_id, parameter_id, date_id, time_id, user_id FROM GGG where device_id like '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' ";



OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql1, con);
con.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable GGG = new DataTable();
da.Fill(GGG);
metroGrid1.DataSource = GGG;
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strSql1 =
```

Better:

```
 performSelect(metroComboBox1.Text, metroComboBox3.Text, date1, date2);
private void performSelect(string param1, string param2, DateTime Date1,DateTime Date2){ 
using(OleDbCommand com = Conn.CreateCommand()){
   com.CommandText = "select * from GGG where device like %@mcb1% and parameter like %@mcb3% and time between @date1 and @date2";
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcb1",param1);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcb3",param2);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1",Date1);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2",Date2);
   com.ExecuteReader();
} 
}
```

If that doesn't work, then please tell us what the values for param1, param2, date1, and date2 are when they enter the method.
"Select * from GGG where device_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' AND time_id Between #"+date1+"# AND #"+date2+"#";

```
"Select * from GGG where device_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox1.Text + "%' AND parameter_id LIKE '%" + metroComboBox3.Text + "%' AND time_id Between #"+date1+"# AND #"+date2+"# AND clock_id between #"+date3+"# and #"+date4+"#"
```

Comment: Sorry - habit. I changed my answer

Comment: Please see the edit on my first line as well. For Acess, change the single quote to a # sign for dates

Comment: thnk's, first line work!!! ComboBox work, and datetimepicker, But only date, not time, may be also have some error

Comment: I don't remember in Acess, but make sure your date field is dateTIME and not just date. In SQL, there is both - so if you add a date field instead of dateTIME you will lose the time portion

Comment: can i add also date3 and date4, for example ?

Comment: Yes - you can add as much as you like, as long as the AddWithValue matches a field in the database table. You can choose any name you like for the @ variable ("@hello or @HELLO or @Date") as long as you put it in the right field in your command (user_Firstname = @HELLO) and you don't need to match datatypes as long as the data you feed matches that in the database AddWithValue("@Date",DateTime.Now) or AddWithValue("@date",DateTime.Now.ToString())

Comment: how it's will be look, like this? AND clock_id Between #" + date3 + "# AND #" + date4 + "#"

Comment: You should reall use parameters but yes - that's how you would do it inline

Comment: can you dopleaze my example, with date3 and date 4(inline). Now i did it, and have error(

Comment: See the last line of my answer above

Comment: Glad to help! Take care.